# Interactions between multi-valued categorical and other categorical variables in R

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

How does one encode interactions between a multi-valued categorical variable with other categorical variables in R? Does everything need to be written manually since multi-valued categorical variables are dummy-coded manually as well?

Answer (score 1):

More of Stackexchange question, but `x ~ y * z` may be what you are looking for as in

```
> exdf <- data.frame(x=11:19, y=c("A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"), 
+                             z=c("D","E","D","E","D","E","E","D","D"))
> fit <- lm(x ~ y*z, data=exdf)
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ y * z, data = exdf)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
 2.776e-17  6.939e-18 -1.000e+00  0.000e+00  1.000e+00 -5.000e-01  5.000e-01 
         8          9 
-5.000e-01  5.000e-01 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   11.000      1.000  11.000  0.00161 **
yB             3.000      1.225   2.449  0.09172 . 
yC             7.500      1.225   6.124  0.00875 **
zE             1.000      1.414   0.707  0.53048   
yB:zE         -1.000      1.871  -0.535  0.63006   
yC:zE         -3.000      1.732  -1.732  0.18169   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.95,     Adjusted R-squared:  0.8667 
F-statistic:  11.4 on 5 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.03627
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this is not what I meant exactly. Assume that y=c("A,B", "A,B,C", "B,A", "B","B","C","C","C","C") so each record in y can have a variable number of levels. Can I still write y * z? Because I would first need to create a dummy encoding for y, right?